# From where can I find App Secret in Dropbox for android?

Tags: android, dropbox-api

I am integrating Dropbox to android app. i created app on dropbox, i got App Key, but i don't know how to get App Secret Key? If you have any idea related to it, than please share with me. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to register Your app first. Then if it is approved by DropBox go to "AppConsole" and push "Options" right besides Your registered app. Here You will find the secret code

[image]