# Not getting the secret key for the app registration in Dropbox

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, dropbox

I am integrating the Dropbox to my application for that I need to register my application in the Dropbox API where after registering my app two kind of keys get generated: 1) App Key and 2) Secret Key. For my case, I sign up with Dropbox and go to the App Console from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers). And registered my app with the related information. After the app get registered properly, I am having only my App Key with that. The secret key is not there. I tried to search for the missing secret key with app registered with Dropbox, but I found only the single [relevant link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187711/from-where-can-i-find-app-secret-in-dropbox-for-android), In which they are saying that once the app gets approved then in the App Console near the push options I will have the General info and with in that the secret key will be there,

So what I want to know is: Whether for getting the secret key of registered apps in the dropbox my app have to be approved by Dropbox, If yes then How much time it take to get confirmation of our app approval or rejection, Or if this is not the case then whats the correct way of registering the app with the Dropbox API?

Any help will be greatly appreciable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, your app doesn't need to be approved to have a secret key. It does, however, have to be the right type. I'm guessing you created a "Drop-ins" app instead of a "Dropbox API" app. (Drop-ins apps don't have app keys.) Try creating a new app and be sure to choose Dropbox API. You should see the app key and secret as soon as you create the app.

Comment: @samarx : Thanks it was my mistake that i was creating the "Drop-ins" app instead "Dropbox API" app. I got the App Key and Secret Key both.

Comment: @samarx : will you please elaborate me that what should i put over the OAuth redirect URIs column in the app settings.

Comment: Maybe you should create a new question to ask about the OAuth redirect URI.

Comment: Thanks for your precious time .